# how to set spinner item value according to the web service particular value in android

Tags: android

I have some items on spinner adapter-{astro,pluto,sun}.I get a value from web service dynamically (ex)pluto.Then how can i set pluto value to spinner for user view.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `Spinner.setSelection()` method to set that corresponding `SpinnerAdapter`'s item based on the web service response.

I hope this will help.